# Grade rounding function giving me 'Logical(0)' when printing - R

Tags: r, function, rounding

I'm trying to round random grades (vector) to the nearest grade (category) with for and if loop. The idea is that the function takes the grades and puts them into a category. The category holds the rounded grades and has the variable 'gradesRounded'. gradesRounded will be returned and printed and this is giving `logical(0)` as output. I would very much like for a vector containing the rounded grades to be the output. How do I fix this? (input/output should be vectors and function name + return(gradesRounded must include due to it being assignment-related) output should be -3, 7, 4, 12, -3

```
roundGrade <- function(grades) {

grades <- c(-3, 7, 3, 11, -2)

gradesRounded <- category

for (i in grades){

if (grades >= -3 & grades <= -2) {category=("-3")}

else if (grades >= -2 & grades <= 00) {category=("00")}

else if (grades >= 1 & grades <= 02) {category=("02")}

else if (grades >= 3 & grades <= 4) {category=("4")}

else if (grades >= 6 & grades <= 7) {category=("7")}

else if (grades >= 8 & grades <= 10) {category=("10")}

else if (grades >= 11 & grades <= 12) {category=("12")}

return(gradesRounded)

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably were trying to do :

```
roundGrade <- function(grades) {
  
  category <- numeric(length(grades))
  for (i in seq_along(grades)) {
    if (grades[i] >= -3 & grades[i] <= -2) {category[i]= -3}
    else if (grades[i] >= -2 & grades[i] <= 0) {category[i]= 0}
    else if (grades[i] >= 1 & grades[i] <= 2) {category[i]= 2}
    else if (grades[i] >= 3 & grades[i] <= 4) {category[i]= 4}
    else if (grades[i] >= 6 & grades[i] <= 7) {category[i]= 7}
    else if (grades[i] >= 8 & grades[i] <= 10) {category[i]= 10}
    else if (grades[i] >= 11 & grades[i] <= 12) {category[i]= 12}
  }
  return(category)
}

grades <- c(-3, 7, 3, 11, -2)
result <- roundGrade(grades)
result
#[1] -3  7  4 12 -3
```

Also have a look at `?cut` and `?findInterval` which is helpful for such cases.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to do that but it turned out messy. 
It works now! also thanks for the suggestions :)